# SQL query sees the value as a column name

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to make a connection to a database and then run an INSERT INTO query, but when the code runs, i get the error: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'BLUE'.`

As you can see in my code below, i give "BLUE" as an value instead of an column name. Does anyone knows what i am doing wrong? p.s. color is an Enum, all the other values are doubles.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO [oval] " +
               "(anchorX, anchorY, width, height, weight, color) VALUES " +
               "(" + drawingItem.getAnchor().getX() +
               ", " + drawingItem.getAnchor().getY() +
               ", " + drawingItem.getWidth() +
               ", " + drawingItem.getHeight() +
               ", " + ((Oval) drawingItem).getWeight() +
               ", " + drawingItem.getColor().toString() + ")";

initConnection();
Statement myStmt = con.createStatement();
rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(query);
closeConnection();
```

**EDIT ANSWER:**

```
String query = "INSERT INTO [oval] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

initConnection();
PreparedStatement myPrepStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
myPrepStmt.setDouble(1, drawingItem.getAnchor().getX());
myPrepStmt.setDouble(2, drawingItem.getAnchor().getY());
myPrepStmt.setDouble(3, drawingItem.getWidth());
myPrepStmt.setDouble(4, drawingItem.getHeight());
myPrepStmt.setDouble(5, ((Oval)drawingItem).getWeight());
myPrepStmt.setString(6, drawingItem.getColor().toString());
rowsAffected = myPrepStmt.executeUpdate();
closeConnection();
```

Comment: Used parameters instead of munging the query string with values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, use parametrized query to prevent SQL injection. As for the problem in hand, you must use single quote to each string values.

Ex:

```
"('" + drawingItem.getAnchor().getX() +
"', '" +
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for such a noobie mistake hihi (Just a beginner programmer). I uploaded the correct code to my question for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way would be:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO [oval] " +
               "(anchorX, anchorY, width, height, weight, color) VALUES " +
               "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

initConnection();
int i = 1;
Statement myStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
myStmt.setInt(i++, drawingItem.getAnchor().getX());
myStmt.setInt(i++, drawingItem.getAnchor().getY());
myStmt.setString(i++, drawingItem.getWidth());
myStmt.setString(i++, drawingItem.getHeight());
myStmt.setFloat(i++, ((Oval) drawingItem).getWeight());
myStmt.setString(i++, drawingItem.getColor().toString());
rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It should be `con.prepareStatement(query)`, and then `myStmt.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, typed this from the memory.